# Protecting sensitive information in Git

Tags: git, github

Assume I have a project I'm working on that is a blog.  In this blog I have a config file with sensitive information in it.  When I decide to push this project to Github, I want the config file filled with example data instead of my sensitive data.  What is the best, and most widely used, method of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach is:

1. fill the config file with dummy data, commit changes and push to GitHub
2. configure git to ignore changes in tracked file:

   git update-index --assume-unchanged ***config-file***
3. fill the config file with sensitive information

Answer (score 6):

Don't put it there in the first place. Check in an example config file with a different name, add the real config file's name to `.gitignore`, and never check it in.

If you've already done commits with your config file in place, use `git filter-branch` to make it go away before you push anywhere public.