# Hide sensitive information from git changes

Tags: git, security

Is there a way to instruct git to hide my sensitive information.
E.g.

### credentials.php (in local repository).

```
Line1: $dbname = 'xyz';
Line2: $dbpassword = 'password';
```

### credentials.php (in github repository and history).

```
Line1: $dbname = 'xyz';
Line2: $dbpassword = 'xxxxxxxx';
```

So git automatically hides the information with 'x'.

If not via git, how should I do it? I try and keep all my credentials in one place, but it becomes hard when you are using 3rd party libraries and they keep credentials all over the place.

**Sidenote:** Its not possible for me to NOT track the `credentials.php` file at all because it may also contain some other logic which needs to be version controlled.

**Note:** I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887733/protecting-sensitive-information-in-git) with a similar question. But the answer is not satisfactory for me. Is there an automated way to do what is told in the "accepted answer" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably are looking for is a filter. You set these up in your `.gitattributes` file to run one substitution upon adding a file to the staging area, and another substitution upon checkout:

[image]

The image is from the .gitattributes section of the [Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes), which has details on how to create such a filter.

Comment: forgive me for the delay, but it will take me some time to read and digest. I will come back and then choose a correct answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

A common solution to this is to have a file `credentials.example.php` which you add to the repository and which does not contain any real credentials but just the general format that is used to specify them, to show others on how to create the *real* `credentials.php`. Because that file is then ignored via the `.gitignore` file so it is not added to the repository. So you can place your actual credentials there for both development or even deployment.

The downside is that you may need to synchronize format changes into both files when the file changes. But you should try to keep such a credentials (or config) file really concise, so it shouldn’t change too often.

Another solution would be to have two configuration files, like `credentials.default.php` and `credentials.user.php` where the former is checked into the repository and the latter is ignored again. The program then attempts to load both (in order), so you can overwrite things in the user file but do not need to respecify *everything*. So if you have many configurations, which defaults are sane (they should), then you probably only need to overwrite a few important configurations (like credentials), so you can just specify those in the user file.

Comment: hmm.. a very elegant solution. But in projects like php-laravel I have more than 15 configuration files that I need to keep track of. Your approach is possibly the best for manageable number of configuration files.

Comment: If it’s possible to modify those configuration files, you could have them all include your single global configuration file which you could then manage per above.

Comment: Oh I would like that, but these are frameworks which expect to find these configuration files in the right place and with the right content.

Comment: Yeah, but if you can change those, you can make those include your file and then provide the information in the format they require.

Comment: you are right. bit of a work ... but definitely correct. If this `git smudge` does not work, this is definitely the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up using a variation of `poke's` answer. **Please redirect all votes to his answer.**

I used `env` variables to solve my problem. Laravel (which I use) uses [phpdotenv framework](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) to handle env variables.

In all my configuration files, I write `env('USERNAME')`, `env('PASSWORD')`, etc variables and I also define a `.env` file in my project's root directory.

## Sample content of .env file

```
USERNAME=rash
PASSWORD=pass
... Other key-value pairs.
```

At runtime, in configuration files, all these keys are replaced by the values defined in this file.

I also define a `.env.example` file where I keep my sample data.

## Sample content of .env.example file

```
USERNAME=PUT_USERNAME_HERE
PASSWORD=PUT_PASSWORD_HERE
...
```

Then I version-control this file. Any user who uses my project, makes a copy of this file, replaces all values with their own, and renames that file to `.env`. The project then runs smoothly.

This solves my problem because:

1. There is no sensitive information in my configuration files. Each conf files have values such as env('USERNAME'). The actual sensitive info is in the `.env` file. Hence I can version-control my conf files.
2. Since I also pass `.env.example` file, the users at other end know exactly what needs to be put in the appropriate fields.
3. It does not matter how many conf files I have. I may have 100 files and still this solution works flawlessly.