# hi there, i want to deploy my app in gitHub and LIVE my app in Heroku but there is some sensitive information in my code. what should i do now?

Tags: node.js, heroku, sensitive-data

I want to deploy my app in gitHub and  LIVE my app in Heroku but there is some sensitive information in my code. what should I do now?

I have a user name and user password to connect my app with cloud-based MongoDB database.

Comment: push your code to some private repository (like gitlab , bitbucket )

Comment: well, this is okay, but it would be great if there is any possibility to deploy my code in GitHub and live it on Heroku.

Comment: then create github private repo , but it costs

Comment: okay, thanks for suggesting me an alternative.

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/163506, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22887771/354577, and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars